# Why is Admiral Daala considered a competent commander?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, character-development

In the Star Wars Legends canon, Admiral [**Natasi Daala**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Natasi_Daala) is often thought of - both by herself and by others - as a competent, even brilliant, commander. And yet, every one of her campaigns was a dismal failure, with most ending in a complete rout. In fact, Daala herself was considered dead on at least three occasions (two of which included the total destruction of her fleet), finally relinquishing her command to [Gilad Pellaeon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gilad_Pellaeon) after the third failed campaign.

Somehow, Daala found herself in the office of Chief of State of the Galactic Alliance, yet she managed to fudge this up as well. In her two years as Chief, she made such increasingly bad decisions that the Jedi Order and several others had to forcefully remove her from office.

**Given this unremitting (and perhaps unmatched) history of failure, what justification is there in-universe to call Daala competent, much less brilliant?**

Comment: [Tv Tropes alert!](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FauxActionGirl)

Comment: you can be competent and still lose every time. it's like being the lowest graded person in the honors class.

Comment: Maybe she is just a better politician than a military commander?

Comment: Maybe she's tactically brilliant, but strategically dumb?  I bet she does a good job of running a ship, but that doesn't mean she'd manage a task group or fleet well.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that this is a galaxy where Admiral Akbar is a 'military genius' because he can recognize a trap seconds after it has sprung.

Comment: @Jeff yep, this seems to be par for the course for 99% of Imperial commanders (excluding Thrawn). She wasn't considered brilliant because she was the Next Alexander, she was brilliant in comparison to all the other failures.

Comment: I might bother posting a canon answer later but IIRC Tarkin observed that she won most of her military exercises early in her career (using male pseudomym iirc). Being Tarkin's squeeze later on clearly didn't hurt her career - and being assigned good troops and given good assignments helps one's reputation for brilliance.

Comment: Also, see Dumbledore, Albus Percival Brian Wulfric. EVERY single one of his combat plans either failed, or had to be saved by an underaged rogue team **despite** his efforts to eff things up.

Comment: @Jeff - Ackbar's reputation largely came from the fact that he had "studied" under Tarkin. Apparently Tarkin enjoyed flaunting his plans & though processes around in front of the "stupid" slave, and as a result, Ackbar basically memorized the Empire's playbook before escaping. Maybe Daala's rep is on equally shaky ground.

Comment: @Jeff As Omegacron pointed out, he was thoroughly versed in Imperial naval tactics and doctrine and no doubt put it to good use both situationally and when crafting and advocating for the Rebel strategy of dispersed operations, particularly on the naval side of things.  I would credit this doctrine as being the foundational reason for the survival of the Rebel fleet and the ultimate success of the Rebellion.  As others have noted, he wasn't brilliant per se but he was above average in regards to competence and had a good head for strategy, organization, and logistics.

Comment: @Antillies - yep, yet Daala doesn't seem to have any of that going for her, either. She consistently has issues getting anyone important to rally behind her, usually having to kill them off instead. And in all three campaigns, it was really her second-in-command doing all the work in regards to logistics. As far as I can tell, all Daala did was come up with battle plans that always failed.

Comment: @DVK - Being Tarkin's girl *is* a conical answer. *You don''t tug on Superman's cape. You don't spit into the wind.* And you don't mess around with the boss's main squeeze (while they're [making] their way to the top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Because she was perceived as such.**

Daala was considerably well-known, even without consideration of her tactical merits, both to her allies and her enemies.  She was [aggressive](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Natasi_Daala#The_reunification_of_the_Empire), [loyal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Natasi_Daala#Revealed_to_the_galaxy), [ruthless](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Natasi_Daala#The_reunification_of_the_Empire), given to passion and [bouts](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Natasi_Daala#The_reunification_of_the_Empire) of insensible rage, and relentless in pursuing those she considered her enemies.

Moff Getelles [described](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Natasi_Daala#Personality_and_traits) her as:

> an erratic officer, a laser cannon with a malfunctioning actuator [...but] she is a hero—she has fought all her enemies, real and imagined, with bravery and ferocity.

To her enemies, she was notorious because she was **dangerous**.  Throughout her career she had access to a [considerable amount of force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Natasi_Daala#Command_of_Maw_Installation), which - combined with her proclivity to become furiously impassioned - gave her the capability of inflicting grave amounts of damage on any given target, often without consideration of [her own losses](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Natasi_Daala#Personality_and_traits).  This made her unpredictable, deadly, and difficult to effectively deal with.

To her allies, her [aggressive](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Natasi_Daala#Revealed_to_the_galaxy), [bold](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Natasi_Daala#Assault_on_the_Jedi_Praxeum) campaigns against the New Republic were a badly needed morale boost in the post-Endor era of seemingly continuous Imperial losses and set backs.  Daala's operations, though ultimately failures, earned her esteem within Imperial circles for at least doing *something*, and no doubt satisfied a commonly held desire to inflict harm upon those responsible for the downcast of the Empire.

Daala's [successes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Natasi_Daala#Revealed_to_the_galaxy) - for she was not without them - however were undercut by her lack of patience and caution, and an overestimation of her own abilities.  Having been the beneficiary of Grand Moff Tarkin's [patronage](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Natasi_Daala#Prot.C3.A9g.C3.A9e_of_Wilhuff_Tarkin), she rose through the ranks perhaps too quickly and failed to gain sufficient experience in the larger considerations of military operations.

This combined with her rashness and near-obsession with claiming vengeance prevented her from consolidating after her victories and taking advantage of her abilities for long-term gain.  Consequently, this caused her performance within the tactical theater to be grossly inconsistent, for she was capable of both [brilliant victories](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Natasi_Daala#Second_Galactic_Civil_War) and [shockingly dismal failures](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Natasi_Daala#Revealed_to_the_galaxy).

This state of dynamic fame and notoriety seems to have coalesced to give Daala a reputation disproportionately inflated both by fear and admiration.  Claims of her being a competent, or even brilliant, commander seem to stem from impressions of her rather than a thorough consideration of her accomplishments and abilities.

Answer (score 3):

There are many famous generals in history who have reputations as competent and even great commanders who have been known to lose battles, campaigns, and even wars.

A losing general can be considered competent if he loses a lot less badly than he should have considering the odds against him.

George Washington was known for losing battle after battle but eventually winning the Revolutionary war, for example.

Comment: You raise a good point, but I'm not aware of ANY major victory on the part of Admiral Daala other than the first surprise attack when she came out of The Maw. The few minor battles that were won during her various campaigns belong to captains of individual ships, in situations where Daala herself wasn't even involved other than being the top of the chain-of-command at the time.